# Best way to split this list into smaller lists?

Tags: python, list, split, enumerate

I've been trying to wrap my head around the best way to split this list of numbers up that are ordered but broken up in sections. Ex:

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36, 44, 45, 46, 47]
```

I'd like the output to be this..

```
sliced_data = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],[29, 30, 31, 32, 33],[35, 36],[44, 45, 46, 47]]
```

I've been trying a while look until it's empty but that isn't working too well..

Edit:

```
for each_half_hour in half_hour_blocks:
    if next_number != each_half_hour:
        skippers.append(half_hour_blocks[:next_number])
        del half_hour_blocks[:next_number]

    next_number = each_half_hour + 1
```

Comment: Whats not working well with it?

Comment: It hangs in a loop. I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why a `while-loop` wouldn't work here, unless you're going for something more efficient or succinct.

Something like:

```
slice = [data.pop(0)]
sliced_data = []
while data:
    if data[0] == slice[-1] + 1:
        slice.append(data.pop(0))
    else:
        sliced_data.append(slice)
        slice = [data.pop(0)]
sliced_data.append(slice)
```

Comment: Both very awesome answers and it helped me wrap my head around my mistakes. I'm going with tijko's for readability.

Comment: @Matthew, This method won't scale well to large lists, so keep that in mind if `data` isn't always going to be short

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36, 44, 45, 46, 47]
>>> from itertools import groupby, count
>>> [list(g) for k,g in groupby(data, key=lambda i, c=count():i-next(c))]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [29, 30, 31, 32, 33], [35, 36], [44, 45, 46, 47]]
```